# How to parse a SQL string into rails Arel object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

After writing some large and complex SQL statements I asked sometime ago [how could I do it in a better way with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885040/better-way-to-write-large-sqls-inside-rails-models). However I ended up using Arel again, because I couldn't nest more conditions if I were calling "find_by_sql".

```
Questions.find_by_sql(HUGE_SQL).by_filter(:popular).order('created_at').limit(5)
```

My goals are:

- Organize sqls in separate files
- Convert those string sqls into Arel objects
- Nest this arel object with common reusable conditions like "limit, order, .."

Thanks

Comment: Arel is only one way library for now. And I don't know anything that can parse and create arel tree.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the magical [scuttle.io](http://www.scuttle.io/) to convert complex SQL queries to Arel. Then, you can create separate methods for each part of your query, and still be able to combine them together. More detail is in this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/camerondutro).

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this so that I could take a filtered scope from a web dashboard and pass it to a background task to generate a CSV export using the same scope. Here's what I came up with:

```rb
def sql_to_scope(model_class, sql)
  model_class.from("(#{sql}) as \"#{model_class.table_name}\"")
end
```

Given a `Customer` model:

```rb
sql_to_scope(Customer, Customer.where('id % 2 = 0').to_sql).find_each { |c| puts c.id }
# 2
# 4
# 6

sql_to_scope(Customer, "select * from customers where id % 2 = 0").pluck(:id)
# => [2, 6, 4]
```

It works be replacing the default FROM clause with a subquery containing the original SQL. I wouldn't be surprised if it fell apart in more complex cases but it works for my simple needs.